# jQuery Masonry + Bootstrap, Grid behaves differently as intended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I've been solving this problem for hours now, I can't seem to make it work the way I intended it to be.

I want my boxes to be setup like this using bootstrap grids:

[image]

Now for some reason It became just only 2 columns after I use the plugin jQuery Masonry (*I used this to handle various div heights*).

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container" >
    <div id="grid" class="row">

      <div class="span5 box box1">1</div>
      <div class="span4 box box2">2</div>
      <div class="span3 box box3">3</div>

      <div class="span5 box box4">4</div>
      <div class="span4 box box5">5</div>
      <div class="span3 box box6">6</div>      

    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box { background: #ccc; margin-bottom: 20px; } 

.box1 { height: 290px; }
.box2 { height: 200px; }
.box3 { height: 300px; }

.box4 { height: 250px; }
.box5 { height: 340px }
.box6 { height: 240px }
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
    });         

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/afihux/3/

I want it to be responsive as much as possible, that is one reason why I used Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

For now, I settled with this approach:

```
.box { background: #ccc; position: relative } 

.box1 { height: 290px; }
.box2 { height: 200px; }
.box3 { height: 300px; }
.box4 { height: 250px; top: 10px; }
.box5 { height: 340px; top: -80px; }
.box6 { height: 240px; top: 20px; }


@media (min-width: 1200px) {

.box4 { top: 20px; }
.box5 { top: -70px }
.box6 { top: 30px }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.box { margin-bottom: 20px; top: 0; }
}
```

**demo:** http://jsbin.com/avupok/1

I played around with the css **top** property to re adjust the total layout.

I think there's no need to use a 3rd party jQuery plugin since the grids are still manageable (only 6 boxes).

I haven't tested yet out if **top** property with a **relative** property works well with other browser. I only had tested it on Google Chrome and Safari. I have a feeling it will break in some browser.

This is open for improvements.